# Большое расстояние между значениями Console.Writeline

Tags: c#, sql-server

При обучении работы с базой данных MS SQL Server, при попытке вывести данные со столбцов `ID`, `Name`, `Points` таблицы `users`, программа по какой-то причине выдает данные строки `Points` с большим отступом как показано на рисунке:

[image: Скрин консольного приложения]

Прошу объяснить мне по почему бывает такая ситуация, и как решить данную проблему.
Код метода:

```
static void print()
{
    DataClassesUserInfoDataContext Userinfo = new DataClassesUserInfoDataContext();
    var custs = from c in Userinfo.users
                select new { Id = c.ID, Name = c.Name, Points = c.Points };
    Console.WriteLine("ID - Name - Points");
    foreach (var cust in custs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", cust.Id, cust.Name, cust.Points);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Нажмите любую клавишу для завершения работы...");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - [{1}] - [{2}]", cust.Id, cust.Name, cust.Points);`

Comment: @Igor https://imgur.com/s1LvgP1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что значения в поле `Name` заканчиваются хвостами из пробелов.

```
Console.WriteLine("[{0}] - [{1}] - [{2}]", cust.Id, cust.Name, cust.Points);
```

Вероятно, тип поля в базе - строковый, фиксированной длины.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", cust.Id, cust.Name.Trim(), cust.Points);
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь в решении проблемы, но я всё же не понимаю как оформить нефиксированную длину для строк в столбце
Вот скрин БД: https://imgur.com/197VQws

Comment: @AndreyPilip `varchar(50)`